# Create a Report based on a value from Combo box in form

Tags: ms-access, vba

I need help with solving a problem of forms and reports. I need to create a form with a Combo box that selects companies with a button to view A REPORT with some values on that selected company from Combo box. How can I do this? I created the combo box and when I press the preview button it displays all the companies. Any suggestions?

Here is my VBA code:

```
Option Compare Database

Private Sub Button_Click()
    'Forms!FormFirmKarnet.Visible = False
    DoCmd.OpenReport "FirmKarnet", acViewPreview
End Sub

Private Sub Close_Click()
    DoCmd.Close acForm, "FormFirmKarnet"
End Sub

Private Sub id_AfterUpdate()
    Forms!FormFirmKarnet!Code_company = Forms!FormFirmKarnet!id.Column(1)
End Sub

Private Sub id_LostFocus()
    Forms!FormFirmKarnet!code_company = Forms!FormFirmKarnet!id.Column(1)
End Sub
```

Comment: The lost focus event is generally not suitable for code such as you show above because it will run every time anyone tabs through the form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case you can open the report with a `where` filter:

```
DoCmd.OpenReport "reportname", acViewPreview, , "Company_ID = " & Me.comboBoxName
```

This presumes that your comboBox has an ID field as the bound column and the field is called `Company_ID` in the query of the report.
The ComboBox does not need any more code for this, you might just have to check if anything is selected before opening the report.

Comment: "doesn't work" without any further descriptions or questions is understood as "...and I have given up and now try becoming a lumber jack."

Comment: !its working :)  sorry, i didn't have internet to answer u !  thanks man